# create a table in sqllite by using a dataframe

Tags: python, sqlite, dataframe, create-table

I'm new to sqllite3 and trying to understand how to create a table in sql environment by using my existing dataframe. I already have a database that I created as "pythonsqlite.db"

```
#import my csv to python
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_csv("my_input_file.csv")


## connect to database
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("pythonsqlite.db")

##push the dataframe to sql 
my_data.to_sql("my_data", conn, if_exists="replace")

##create the table

conn.execute(
    """
    create table my_table as 
    select * from my_data
    """)
```

However, when I navigate to my SQLlite studio and check the tables under my database, I cannot see the table I've created. I'd really appreciate if someone tells me what I'm missing here.

Comment: I ran your code with `my_data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` and it worked as expected, both tables were created and populated.

Answer (score 2):

I replaced just one part of the code, the 'read_csv' instead I create a small dataframe (see below), I think the issue will be either with the name of your script ( example: pandas.py)

```
import pandas as pd

# my_data = pd.read_csv("my_input_file.csv")
columns = ['a','b']
my_data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=columns)


## connect to database
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("pythonsqlite.db")

##push the dataframe to sql 
my_data.to_sql("my_data", conn, if_exists="replace")

##create the table

conn.execute(
    """
    create table my_table as 
    select * from my_data
    """)
```

I ran it and I don't see to have a problem
[image]

Comment: Could it be that the author of the question could not generate a valid dataframe with read_csv? If you could also mention how to handle that, the answer would be very thorough.